# Write uploaded file to linux server from asp.net mvc 4.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to upload an uploaded file to both where my mvc 4.0 application runs and to another server that is powered by linux based server. I want to upload file to directory under tomcat server(ex: KGS/assets/). I can upload file to local server by the following code

```
public ActionResult Upload(string qqfile, int id)
        {
            //resim ekliyor
            const string path = @"C:\Temp\";
            const string kgsPath =@"\\";
            try
            {
                var stream = Request.InputStream;
                string file;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["qqfile"]))
                {
                    // IE
                    HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
                    stream = postedFile.InputStream;
                    file = Path.Combine(path, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Webkit, Mozilla
                    file = Path.Combine(path, qqfile);
                }

                var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
        }
```

Are there anyways or approaches to achieve this or is this impossible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You must expose some way of storing the file on the Linux server that your ASP.NET application can use.  This could be a Samba or NFS share, an FTP account, a web service, etc.  The storage mechanism you choose will dictate how you store the file there.

Another option would be to use something like [rsync](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rsync) to keep files in both places synchronized.  Your .NET application would be unaware of this, so no coding required.